# How to make a stroke with only increasing width

Tags: shapes, stroke, affinity-designer

I want to be able to make a stroke that only becomes wider, but in affinity designer, it seems that the start and end has to be the same width. Is there a way?

AI width tool:
[image: AI Width tool]

Affinity designer:
[image: Affinity designer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Option/Alt click the start or end node in the pressure profile, you can move it independently of the other end.

[image]

Sadly, it looks like the rounded end-caps get messed up if the end nodes are sharp nodes rather than smooth:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for, thanks!